# How to import localforage to service worker using importScripts?

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox, localforage

I'm trying to import localforage to my service-worker.js file. I've read, you have to use
importScripts() to do so. Thing is I installed localforage in my Vue project using yarn and now i'm not sure where to access the localforage file.

I tried:

- importScripts('localforage.js')
- importScripts('localforage')
- importScripts('localforage.min.js')

resulting in: service-worker.js:6 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://webprojectname/localforage.min.js' failed to load.
at https://webprojectname/service-worker.js:6:1
and: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

I searched a lot googling but didn't find a solution.
Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you file is served with the wrong MIME type. Check your server config.

Comment: I don't know were to check! In my opinion it has nothing to do with the server. I use localforage in other components as well but there i can import it like every other library with import localForage from 'localforage'

Comment: The error message tells you that you're trying to load a file and it fails because it has a Mime type of 'text/html' instead of 'application/javascript'. This is usually caused by some misconfiguration at the server level. You could check your .htaccess if you're on Apache server